# Create a Kotlin Library (not multiplatform) in IntelliJ

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm developing a math themed Android App (in Kotlin) and want to implement the logic (so the math part) in an external library. My question is:

How can I create a project, that I can use as a library, so that I can import it in other projects (e.g. the actual Android project).

I know I can create a "multiplatform library" or an "android library", but I don't want to implement platform specific implementations (for js, native...). I just want to write my code in Kotlin.

Is it possible just to ignore the platform specific implementations? Can I just create a normal kotlin project and import that? Thanks in advance.